# Git Allow "push to master" access to particular user in LDAP account

Tags: git, hook, gitlab, githooks

I have a pre-push hook enabled for a repository.

Now, I need to exclude one particular user from the hook restriction. and allow only that user to push.

May I know, is there any way to achieve this?

Note: I can simply use --no-verify to bypass the check, but I need to enforce this to add more security to the repository.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that a simple [`git push --no-verify`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) allows a user to completely bypass that hook.

> The default is `--verify`, giving the hook a chance to prevent the push.
>   With `--no-verify`, the hook is bypassed completely.

So any user can chose to skip the pre-push hook.

Comment: Thanks. This is very quick and easy step. But, this --no-verify is very weak security that any user can do without my (admin's) knowledge.

Comment: Is there any stronger security way we can achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you can centralize your checks on the server side, with a pre-receive hook. That cannot be bypassed.

Comment: @santhoshkumar - would insist editing the question with security implementation point to mark a good sample.

Comment: @VonC Thanks, I will add pre-receive hook on the custom hooks directory on the server.